# How to add custom image as emoji in android

Tags: android, html, image, keyboard, textview

i've been searching but got no results on adding custom images as emoji in android application.Thank you for any kind of help

Here is my problem :

I've trying to do a custom keyboard in android which includes only custom images as emoji,i manage to show image in keyboard but when i try to send it ,i get [OBJ] in return.

Here is some of my code , i tried many possible ways ;

```
  String s = "<img src='a.png'/>";

     //  Spanned cs = Html.fromHtml("<img src='" +  getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a) + "'/>", imageGetter, null);

              /*  ic.commitText( Html.fromHtml(s, new Html.ImageGetter() {
                    @Override public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
                        Drawable drawFromPath;
                        int path =
                                emoji.this.getResources().getIdentifier(source, "drawable",
                                        "com.cmosteknoloji.emoji");
                        drawFromPath = (Drawable) emoji.this.getResources().getDrawable(path);
                        drawFromPath.setBounds(0, 0, drawFromPath.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                                drawFromPath.getIntrinsicHeight());
                        return drawFromPath;
                    }
                }, null),1);*/

                Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(s, this, null);
                ic.commitText(spanned,1);
```

> 

```
@Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int id = 0;

        if(arg0.equals("a.png")){
            id = R.drawable.a;
        }
        LevelListDrawable d = new LevelListDrawable();
        Drawable empty = getResources().getDrawable(id);
        d.addLevel(0, 0, empty);
        d.setBounds(0, 0, empty.getIntrinsicWidth(), empty.getIntrinsicHeight());

        return d;
   }
```

> 

```
ImageGetter imageGetter = new ImageGetter() {
                @Override
                public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {    
                    byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode("iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==",Base64.DEFAULT);
                    Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);      
                    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);

                    Log.e("Chk", "Height : "+d.getIntrinsicHeight());
                    Log.e("Chk", "Width : " + d.getIntrinsicWidth());                       

                    return d;
                }
            };
```

Comment: hi i am trying to the same can you help me if you were able to this and any sample as well